# Set selected value of a dropdown in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to set the selected value in a dropdown in a razor view.

```
       <select id="drpStatus" name="status">
               <option value="A">Active</option>
               <option value="S">Suspended</option>
               <option value="T">Terminated</option>
               <option value="D">Deleted</option>
       </select>

//I am trying with the below code, based on the value in Model, I want to set the  particular option as selected 
<option selected=@{if(@Model!=null && @Model.Status=='A'){'selected'}} value="A">Active</option>
```

Above code is not working, please let me know if I am working in a right direction or is there any other/better way to achieve it.

Comment: This view is for editing a particular entry?

Comment: @WannaCSharp, yes to edit a particular record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from your controller

**Controller :**

```
var record = db.Records.Find(id);
ViewBag.DropStatus = new SelectList(ListOfStatus, record.Status);
```

The first parameter for SelectList should be an IEnumerable which will serve as the data source for your DropDownList, the second parameter is for the selected value, so just pass the status property of the record you want to edit.

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", string.Empty)
```

The first parameter is the name of the ViewBag we assigned in the controller, it will also serve as the name when you post the data. Hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

The following is one of some possible solutions

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Func<char, MvcHtmlString> function = (c) => Model != null && Model.Status == c 
    ? MvcHtmlString.Create("selected='selected'") 
    : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<select id="drpStatus" name="status">
    <option @function('A') value="A">Active</option>
    <option @function('S') value="S">Suspended</option>
    <option @function('T') value="T">Terminated</option>
    <option @function('D') value="D">Deleted</option>
</select>
```

It would be better to use `SelectList` in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is using Razor's helper tag in the cshtml:

```
@helper SetGender(string dropdownvalue)
{
    var selected = string.Format("value=\"{0}\"", dropdownvalue);
    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownvalue) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.GetClaim(ClaimTypes.Gender.ToString()))) ||
        (User.GetClaim(ClaimTypes.Gender.ToString()) == dropdownvalue))
    {
        selected = string.Concat("selected='selected' ", selected);
    }

    @Html.Raw(selected);
}

<select name="gender">
    <option @SetGender("") >-not set-</option>
    <option @SetGender("male") >male</option>
    <option @SetGender("female") >female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
@{
    List<SelectListItem> lstOrderTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
    lstOrderTypes.Add(new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "plan1" });
    lstOrderTypes.Add(new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "plan2" });
}
@functions {
    public static string GetString(IHtmlContent content)
    {
        var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

@{
    var x = GetString(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderType));
}

<select>
  @foreach (SelectListItem option in lstOrderTypes)
  {
      <option value="@option.Value" selected="@(option.Value == x)">@option.Text</option>
  }
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you clean up the formatting and add a few lines of explanation?